# Define a class variable member in cpp file

Tags: c++

I am trying to declare a class member variable in .h file and define it in .cpp file but in VS2019 I get the error: "redeclaration of member is not allowed". The example of my code is:

.h file

```
#include<iostream>
class test
{
  public:
    test();
    int a;
    static int v;
};
```

And the .cpp file is:

```
#include"test.h"
int test::v = 231;    Here it works since v is static
int test::a = 12;     Here the problem..
test::test(){}
```

Comment: For this to work you need static member variables. Remember a class is meant to have more than 1 instance so there is no way to address your `a` member without an instance.

Comment: Ok. So am I not allowed to define it in cpp file if it is not static? I thought that with the :: operator I could link the variable. For the functions it works, from this point my reasoning.

Comment: ***the :: operator I could link the variable.*** Only a static member.

Comment: You could initialize `a` in the constructor `test::test() : a{12} {}`

Comment: Yes I know that type of initialization. My doubts derives from the fact that for member functions (also not static function) it works. So am I allowed to use to link static variable, function but not normal variable?

Comment: You have to use :: to implement member functions outside of the class definition. If you did not use `test::test()` in the cpp file and instead used test() you would be creating a free function that has no relation to the class test.

Comment: Yes, but I do not totally understand why I can not use the same operator for a simple variable. Just because is not possible (a syntactic error) or for a logical error.

Comment: The difference is there is one instance of the function but can be more than 1 instance of the `a` member and there is no way to address them so `test::a` does not work.

Comment: Ah. I got it... Thank you. I forgot the functions are shared between objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For nonstatic members, you'll need an instance of the class to change variables. For example:

```
// In the .cpp file
test test_1;
test_1.a = 1; // note that there is no need to include the type here

test test_2;
test_2.a = 2;

assert(test_1.a != test_2.a); // since they are two separate instances
```

Nonstatic members don't need to be defined explicitly like static members do.

Answer (score 0):

You declare v to be a class level variable, and a to be an instance/object variable. You can set the default value of a with a constructor.

The .h file:

```
#include<iostream>
class test
{
  public:
    test() a(12) {};
    test(int a_default) a(a_default) {};
    int a;
    static int v;
};
```

The .cpp file:

```
#include"test.h"
int test::v = 231; // works here, as v is static
test t1;   // works here, uses object/instance default
test t2 = test(12);   // works here, provides object/instance default
```

Comment: As I said to TonyK, I was just doing some experiment to better understand. I know the "common way' to initialize the variable. Thanks anyway for your kind answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably what you want:

```
#include<iostream>
class test
{
  public:
    test();
    int a=12; // <<---
    static int v;
};
```

Comment: Actually I knew I could do like this. I was just do some "experiment" to better understand. But thanks for your time.